# Volume under sphere bounded by cylinder and plane $z=0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

[image]

Hello, I've tried calculating the volume under the sphere using these integrating bounds but it gives me the wrong answer.

Comment: What is your answer? And the correct one?

Comment: I already erased my answer, but it should've been 32/9 - 2pi/3

Comment: The limits should be $\theta\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $r\in[0,2\cos(\theta)]$, $z\in [0,2-\sqrt{4-r^2}]$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I also noticed my sketch was wrong as well, is there a way to have different bounds (like mine) where 0 <= z <= 2 and for r something in terms of z?

Comment: Using your bounds gave me the correct answer :)